# Quarkus: Using Gradle Jandex Plugin vs beans.xml descriptor to discover beans

Tags: gradle, quarkus, multi-module, jandex

We have a large multi-module legacy project that we migrated to Quarkus. So far we used Jandex in all modules that define beans. Since Gradle 7.3.3 we have the log full of warnings complaining about implicit dependencies. If I get it right, they are caused by the Jandex plugin and according to https://github.com/kordamp/jandex-gradle-plugin/issues/9, this can not easily be fixed.
Since the Quarkus documentation (https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference) says that modules having a META-INF/beans.xml descriptor present will be scanned for beans, I'm wondering what the impact will be, if I place bean descriptions in the modules and remove the Jandex-Plugin from the project's convention-plugin.
Will the build be slower? Will everything work the same? Is it a bad idea for some reason? (E.g. will every dependency scan all its dependecies again?) Are there limitations I'm maybe not aware of?

Comment: It should be a little slower, as Quarkus has to jandex the dependency itself. Other than that, it should be the same thing.

Comment: I managed a way to set the tasks dependencies correctly. This way we can continue using the Gradle Jandex plugin.